# Can I configure pydev to automatically compile cython files?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, distutils, cython

I'm just picking up Cython.  I'm using it to build a core library in my Python project.  Currently I've configured a `setup.py` file with `distutils` and am running the following command whenever I want to recompile the Cython file:

```
python ./setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

However, I often forget.  I like how Eclipse automatically builds class files for Java every time I edit/save.  Is it possible to configure similar behavior for PyDev, Eclipse, or some other clever way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now there's no special support in PyDev to automatically compile cython files when they change... if you want you can create an external builder:

Right click project > properties > builders > new > program, then configure the program as python having as a parameter the module to run and receiving as arguments also the ${build_files} variable.

You should probably check if some changed file is a .pyx file and if it is, call the actual build command for that file -- and maybe dependencies.

Comment: There is cython support though http://pydev.blogspot.com/2011/10/pydev-cython.html

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain automatically cython compiling using a "magic" [sitecustomize.py](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#pyximport) in your base PYTHONPATH that calls [pyximport](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html#pyximport-cython-compilation-the-easy-way), even if it requires some installation details (such as, under windows, your mingw location), here is an example :

```
import pyximport
import os
import numpy
#import cython
import Cython.Compiler.Options as Options
Options.cimport_from_pyx = True

if os.name == 'nt':
    if os.environ.has_key('CPATH'):
        os.environ['CPATH'] = os.environ['CPATH'] + numpy.get_include()
    else:
        os.environ['CPATH'] = numpy.get_include()

    # XXX: we're assuming that MinGW is installed in C:\MinGW (default)
    if os.environ.has_key('PATH'):
        os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ';C:\MinGW\bin'
    else:
        os.environ['PATH'] = 'C:\MinGW\bin'

    mingw_setup_args = { 'options': { 'build_ext': { 'compiler': 'mingw32' } } }
    pyximport.install(setup_args=mingw_setup_args)
elif os.name == 'posix':
    if os.environ.has_key('CFLAGS'):
        os.environ['CFLAGS'] = os.environ['CFLAGS'] + ' -I' + numpy.get_include()
    else:
        os.environ['CFLAGS'] = ' -I' + numpy.get_include()

    pyximport.install()

pyximport.DEBUG_IMPORT = True
```

As a side note, if you are under windows, please keep in mind that your cython must be [slightly modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531983/easy-install-u-cython-fails-complaining-about-vcvarsall-bat-and-mno-cygwin) to use mingw.

You should also call your files *.pyx for this to work. Another advice : you should use the cython "pure python" [syntax](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html) so that the Pydev editor will not complain.