# 'easy_install -U cython' fails complaining about vcvarsall.bat and -mno-cygwin

Tags: python, windows, mingw, cython, easy-install

Under Windows, it seems that `easy_install` with a C dependency isn't very easy.

### Attempt 1 - `vcvarsall.bat` errors

I am installing `cython` under Windows7, with `MinGw`; I modified Windows7's `PATH` to include `C:\MinGw\bin`.  At this point, I tried to `easy_install -U cython`, and got...

```
C:\Users\mike_pennington\Desktop\TestDrive>easy_install -U cython
Searching for cython
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cython/
Reading http://www.cython.org
Reading http://cython.org
Best match: Cython 0.15.1
Downloading http://cython.org/release/Cython-0.15.1.zip
Processing Cython-0.15.1.zip
Running Cython-0.15.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\mike_p~1\appdata
\local\temp\easy_install-qr1tet\Cython-0.15.1\egg-dist-tmp-556kzq
Compiling module Cython.Plex.Scanners ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Scanning ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Parsing ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Visitor ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Code ...
Compiling module Cython.Runtime.refnanny ...
warning: no files found matching 'bugs.txt' under directory 'tests'
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

C:\Users\mike_pennington\Desktop\TestDrive>
```

### Attempt 2 - Fix `vcvarsall.bat` errors

Next, following the advice of a blog I found, I also tried putting this in `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg` to fix the `vcvarsall.bat` error.

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

This only helps marginally...

```
C:\Python27\Lib\DISTUT~1>easy_install -U cython
Searching for cython
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cython/
Reading http://www.cython.org
Reading http://cython.org
Best match: Cython 0.15.1
Downloading http://cython.org/release/Cython-0.15.1.zip
Processing Cython-0.15.1.zip
Running Cython-0.15.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\mike_p~1\appdata
\local\temp\easy_install-kfif_o\Cython-0.15.1\egg-dist-tmp-o1tbkp
Compiling module Cython.Plex.Scanners ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Scanning ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Parsing ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Visitor ...
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Code ...
Compiling module Cython.Runtime.refnanny ...
warning: no files found matching 'bugs.txt' under directory 'tests'
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

C:\Python27\Lib\DISTUT~1>
```

### Caveat - No cygwin or precompiled binaries

I realize that I might be able to get this working under `cygwin`; however, I don't want  `cygwin` dependencies on this library; I need native Windows7 output.

If possible, I would like to avoid [precompiled Cython binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython) because as the author says, they are "unsupported and for testing purposes only".

### Question

How can I get `cython` to install via `easy_install` under Windows7 with `MinGw`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After more some googling, I found guidance that recommended removing `-mno-cygwin` from `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py` because of a [distutils bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue12641).

Removing `-mno-cygwin` from `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py` got `cython` to compile.

Comment: This fix does not work for me, but creates a new bug:

`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: @MFB, what error are you getting after removing `-mno-cygwin`?  What version of python?

Comment: @MikePennington, I went to go reproduce the error, and now I have a new error entirely.  Sorry for the bum-steer.  The new error is `chmod error` which I thought might have been UAC related, but I switched that off completely.  Any thoughts?